# aws-cdk ignoring tsconfig paths and typeroots

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have a project making use of AWS-CDK all written in TypeScript.

I have a local folder called typings which contains my "global" types - there are no imports/exports there.

I am able to use these types anywhere in my code *except* in my cdk app definitions. Meaning I can make a cdk stack that contains a lambda with these non imported types but I cannot use these types directly in my cdk app build files. TS just says it cannot find them.

I had a similar issue with jest (ts-jest) where it could not find the `paths`. This was resolved using a module that assists in this `import 'tsconfig-paths/register'` and I suspect CDK has the same issue - it disregards my tsconfig. I am using this `import 'tsconfig-paths/register'` to deal with paths as well but no idea how to fix it not finding my types. While I haven't yet tried it I also suspect jest will have same typing issue. Seems related to running cli scripts.

tsconcig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
      "handlers/*": ["src/handlers/*"],
      "config/*": ["src/config/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "typings"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Sample cdk app:

```
import 'tsconfig-paths/register'

const app = new App()

// leter in some stack
addEventRule(events: EventType[]) { // EventType is a custom declaration
  
  new Rule(this, 'ModuleLambdaBuilderRule', {
    ...
  }).addTarget(...)
```

My custom type in typings/common.ts

```
Type EventType = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

In the above - I cannot use `EventType` anywhere in the cdk files. But I can use it fine in any of my lambda code for example.

How can I resolve this? I admit I am a bit lost in the current process of doing things - evidently `typeRoots` is a patch I am not supposed to really use. I tried adding all my files using `includes` and `files` tsconfig option but no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm ok. I guess I need to import these files without any assignment.

I have many type files - they contain no imports/exports.
I created an index.ts file in which:

```
import './foo'
import './bar'
```

Then in my cdk file:

```
import './typings'
```

Not sure what is going in here. Some export voodoo. I had assumed I could not import something that was not exported. I'm rolling with it.

Comment: `import "path"` simply loads the file.
it doesn't actually assign anything. The file imported is the one assigning the types